# PHP work out the majority value

Tags: php

Is it possible to use PHP to work out the majority from multiple vales?

For example if we had three values:

`Agree=5`, `Disagree=2` and `None=1`

can PHP be used to identify that `Agree` and `None` (both together) total `6` and is therefore greater than `Disagree`?

If `Agree` and `None` are greater than `Disagree` then the value can be `true`, otherwise `false`?

Once this has been done then save the result as a value `$total`?

Comment: did you mean greater than `disagree`?

Comment: are you asking if PHP has arithmetic operators and comparison operators? Yes. It does. Please refer to the [language reference](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$agree = 5;
$disagree = 2;
$none = 1;

if(($agree+$none)>$disagree)
{
    echo "true";
    $total = $agree+$none;
}
else
{
    echo "false";
    $total = $agree+$none;    
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$total = ($agree+$none > $disagree) ? TRUE : FALSE;`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the part `? TRUE : FALSE;` do?

Comment: no need for ternary, nor brackets and the variable is misnamed because $total is not what you get from the expression.

Comment: It's just shorthand for an if/else statement, called the Ternary Operator. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: and its not needed here because the expression will already return a boolean http://codepad.org/5HHnLUIn

Comment: Gordon is right, you could just do something like `$is_agree_greater = $agree+$none > $disagree;`